# Sum of the first m terms of the expansion $(x+y)^n$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Let $S(x, y, m, n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m \binom{n}{i}x^i y^{n-i}$, where $0 < m < n$. I want to derive the relation between $S(x, y, m, n)$ and $S(x, y, m, n-1)$.

Is there any formulas I can use?

Comment: As a function of $y$, this $S(x,y,m,n)$ can be seen as the remainder in the Taylor expansion of order $n-m+1$ with center  in the point $x$ for the function $f(t)=t^n$, so one can express it by the integral formula.

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks. In that case, do I need the approximation?

Comment: If an integral formula is ok to you, you just need to apply the integral form of the remainder. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can construct the relation using the identity
$$
\binom{n}{i} = \binom{n-1}{i} + \binom{n-1}{i-1}
$$
Then, writing the $i=0$ term separately,
\begin{eqnarray}
S(x,y,m,n) &=& y^n + \sum_{i=1}^{m} \binom{n-1}{i} x^i y^{n-i}
+ \sum_{i=1}^{m} \binom{n-1}{i-1} x^i y^{n-i} \\
&=& y^n + y\sum_{i=1}^{m} \binom{n-1}{i} x^i y^{n-1-i}
+ \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \binom{n-1}{i} x^{i+1} y^{n-i-1} \\
&=& y S(x,y,m,n-1) + x\left[ S(x,y,m,n-1) - \binom{n-1}{m} x^m y^{n-1-m} \right] \\
&=& (x+y) S(x,y,m,n-1) \ - \ \binom{n-1}{m} x^{m+1} y^{n-1-m}
\end{eqnarray}