# Sum of part of consecutive terms of expansion of (x+y)^n

Tags: co.combinatorics, recurrences

Let $S(x, y, m_1,m_2, n) = \sum\limits_{i=m_1}^{m_2} \binom{n}{i}x^i y^{n-i}$, where $0 < m_1\leq m_2 < n$. I want to derive the relation between $S(x, y, m_1, m_2, n)$ and $S(x, y, m_1-1, m_2, n-1)$.

Is there any formulas I can use? Similarly to [Sum of the first m terms of the expansion $(x+y)^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414224/sum-of-the-first-m-terms-of-the-expansion-xyn).

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that, with
$$
T(x, y, m, n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m \binom{n}{i}x^i y^{n-i}
$$
you have
$$
S(x, y, m_1, m_2, n)= T(x, y, m_2, n)-T(x, y, m_1-1, n)  
$$

Now using the formula for $T$ in the provided link, you can connect now $S(x,y,m_1, m_2,n)$ to $S(x,y,m_1, m_2,n-1)$. Finally
$$
S(x,y,m_1, m_2,n-1)+\binom{n}{m_1-1}x^{m_1-1} y^{n-m_1}=S(x,y,m_1-1, m_2,n-1)
$$
allows you connect the two you want.

Comment: You refer to "the provided link", but you do not seem to have provided one.

Comment: @LSpice The OP states this problem as follow-up to a question. And he provided the link.

Comment: Ah, then the provided link is [Sum of the first m terms of the expansion $(x+y)^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414224/sum-of-the-first-m-terms-of-the-expansion-xyn).